# Unable to inject less variables when parsing string from PHP in lessphp

Tags: php, less, lessphp

I've got the following `less` code. I've read around that there is a limitation in `less.js` when using variables in `url()` declaration and so i used two suggested workarounds, but the real problem is that the variable comes from PHP and it seem it's not passed correctly, as it's never interpreted.

I'm using [`lessphp`](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp)

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

PHP code

```
$this->parsed_css = $this->lessc->parse( $this->parsed_css, array( 'fontdir', 'myfontdir' ) );
```

`Less` code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url(%("%s/fontawesome-webfont.eot", @fontdir));
    src: url('@{fontdir}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('@{fontdir}/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('@{fontdir}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('@{fontdir}/fontawesome-webfont.svgz#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg'),
         url('@{fontdir}/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: @fontdir;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

CSS output

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  src:url("/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
  src:url('/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fontawesome-webfont.svgz#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg'), url('/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesomeRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight:;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

As you can see the variable is never interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your original question (before you removed it in an edit), the variable's name is `$font_dir`, but you're using `fontdir` (no underscore) in all references.

Try assigning the `fontdir` element a value with `array('fontdir' => $font_dir)`, such as:

```
$this->parsed_css = $this->lessc->parse( $this->parsed_css, array( 'fontdir' => $font_dir, 'myfontdir' => $my_font_dir) );
```

Comment: No i'm not even passing the variable, `$this->parsed_css = $this->lessc->parse( $this->parsed_css, array( 'fontdir', 'myfontdir' ) );`, i will later on pass a variable, as of now i hardcoded it

Comment: Yep yopu are right and i'm an idiot, `array( 'fontdir', 'myfontdir' )` should be  `array( 'fontdir' => 'myfontdir' )`. Thanks! :)

Comment: No need for name calling =P; it's a common mistake (and I've made it plenty of times) - some systems do key/value pairing with index 0 vs 1 (like you originally had) and some do them with PHP's 'key'=>'value' method.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded `less` and tested it, the array thing doesn't seem to be the only reason your code isn't working.

This isn't valid `less` code (At least according to the [documentation](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php))

```
src: url('@{fontdir}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
//         ^       ^    Remove these

//Right
echo $less->parse("color: @color",
    array(
        'color' => 'red'
)); //color:red;

//Wrong
echo $less->parse("color: @{color}",
        array(
            'color' => 'red'
    )); // (no output)
```

Comment: No the sintax is correct ( and i think it's required since i'm concatenating into url(), outside it shouldn't be used ), i had to do some extra work to have everything working, like escaping the variable for less since it had a : inside, but the problem here was with the array

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti, very strange! Because I even tested the exact same `less` code you posted, didn't work. Well, happy you solved it!